# Can a separated/torn o-ring cause a P0106 error?

Tags: cel, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor, land-rover, range-rover

I have a 2011 Land Rover Range Rover Sport HSE with approximately 92k miles on it. About 2 months ago, the check engine light came on and my reader gave a P0106 error. Considering the mileage, it seemed most likely that the MAP sensor had done its job and I purchased a [new one](https://www.oreillyauto.com/detail/c/standard-intermotor/standard-intermotor-3-terminal-manifold-absolute-pressure-map-sensor/sti0/as419?q=AS419&pos=0) that I also installed.

Before installing the new MAP sensor I made sure to read different Q&As and it seemed like most people did not recommend using grease. However, due to following this tip, the o-ring, due to friction, slightly separated/tore off the sensor when I installed it. I assumed that it may still do its job since the sensor is screwed on, but at the same time had a nagging feeling that it may affect the performance of my car.

With all of this being said, the check engine light went away after installing the new sensor. However, I have had a feeling that the car hasn't had quite the same power as prior to the initial error, but the same time, I was also considering that it was all in my head.

Now, about 2 months later, the check engine light and P0106 error came back and I'm wondering if it's reasonable to assume that the separated/torn o-ring causing a vacuum leak is the reason for the error? If so, can I feel safe using [silicone-based grease](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Danco-Grease/1092167) to not repeat the same mistake or is another type of grease preferred?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I doubt the o-ring would be enough of an issue to throw the P0106 code. I would think you'd need quite a bit more non-metered air entering your intake for it to throw this code. You can absolutely try to put silicone based grease on what is there already to see if this helps cure anything up. You could even try putting a new o-ring in place, or just plug it up some other way (temporarily) so there is no chance of air passing by the MAP and see if that helps. Seriously, though, I'm thinking it might be air coming in from somewhere else.

Comment: Considering the low cost of an o-ring, I think it makes sense to obtain a replacement and see if that clears up the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Plugging it up first to confirm or dismiss the theory sounds like a great first step. Unfortunately, part of the issue is that the o-ring seems to be glued to the sensor, so it's not easy to only replace the o-ring without having residue left from the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping out the MAP sensor for a new one did remove the CEL and my reader stopped throwing the error after driving for about 20 miles.

When installing the new MAP sensor (with silicone grease) there was a clear "plop" sound that the old one (with the separated/torn o-ring) never did, even before it tore. My guess is that the old one simply wasn't sealing properly and that the new one is.